# What's the best practice to only allow another tomcat webapp redirects link to Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, access-rights

I want to add access rights to Wordpress. only allow the users that already login the application on tomcat, can access the Wordpress.

Application(tomcat, not in AWS) ----allow access--->  Wordpress (AWS)

External users cannot access Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [WP REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) , After verifying tomcat user authentication, If success redirect ti WordPress site

Comment: So, i need to setup the security plugin on Wordpress first ? then use WP REST API to get the access rights from Wordpress.

Comment: what security plugin ?

Comment: not security plugin, just have to be Wordpress account login.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used the JWT(https://jwt.io/) approach with RSA algorithm.

Tomcat side generate the token, and redirect to wordpress url with token
Write a customized Wordpress-plugin to verify the token.